# Re-assigning delegate doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

If I at first do this on a "Cat" object:

```
self.feeder.delegate = self;
```

Then later do this

```
Dog *dog = [[Dog alloc] init];

dog.feeder = cat.feeder;
dog.feeder.delegate = dog;

NSLog(@"DELEGATE: %@", dog.feeder.delegate); //this logs a DOG
```

The delegate methods get called for the Cat, but not the Dog, even though when I log the delegate it says the dog is the delegate.

How can I properly re-assign the delegate?

Comment: Can you add the code of your `Cat` and your `Dog` classes, and some other relevant code please?

Comment: Where does the self.feeder.delegate=self get executed?  It looks like that assignment is happening after you have assigned the dog as the feeder, so the delegate is getting reset

Comment: No, as stated, the Cat is first assigned as the delegate. The Dog is later assigned, but the Cat delegate methods still get called.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that these are not the same feeders. You are saying:

```
self.feeder.delegate = self; // self is a Cat
```

Then later you say this:

```
dog.feeder = cat.feeder;
```

But `cat` is not `self`, so these are two different cats and two different feeders. Perhaps you meant to say

```
dog.feeder = self.feeder;
```

Comment: I presume that the first assignment happens inside the cat class and the second block of code is outside.  The OP needs to post more code to explain what is going on

Comment: @Paulw11 Absolutely. My answer is just a wild guess. It has to be, since the OP has said nothing about his architecture or intentions or where any of this code is. It's a nonquestion at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say dog.feeder = self.feeder. But that doesn't really solve anything. The delegate methods of Dog still do not get called.

Comment: Order of execution is important. As you have a single feeder, you can only have a single feeder delegate at any point in time. If the delegate methods in dog aren't being called then the delegate has been re-assigned or you are dealing with different objects as per @matt's answer. Have you put a breakpoint into the feeder before you call the delegate to inspect the delegate property?

Comment: Yes, at the breakpoint the delegate is nil. But it's not nil when I assign dog.feeder.delegate = dog;

Comment: Try using the zombies template in Instruments